# NSTextView doesn't call controlTextDidChange:

Tags: objective-c, class, delegates, text-editor, nstextview

I have a class ("TextEditorViewController") within there is a NSTextView ("textView") Object. I've connected it with the NSTextView in my .xib file. Here my .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TextEditorViewController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;           // connected in MainMenu.xib
    IBOutlet NSTextField *displayCharacters; // connected in MainMenu.xib
}

@end
```

And here is my .m file:

```
#import "TextEditorViewController.h"    

@implementation TextEditorViewController

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"applicationDidFinishLaunching called"); // printed to the debugger
    [textView setDelegate:(id)self];
}

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj {
    NSLog(@"controlTextDidChange called"); // don't printed to the debugger ???
    [displayCharacters setIntValue:[[textView string] length]];
}

@end
```

But when I change the text in my NSTextView it don't call controlTextDidChange:!
Why?

Thanks for answers! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after rebuilding the files in a new project. Seems like a file management configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Move the delegate part to viewDidLoad.
Why do you don't put this to a viewcontroller?

Comment: You mean awakeFromNib? viewDidLoad doesn't exist for Mac OS X. I tried awakeFromNib but it still don't work :(

Comment: Sorry I thought it's about iOS.

Comment: Nothing... I called NSLog in controlTextDidChange: but there is no output. When I set a breakpoint in that method it won't stop if I change the text.

Comment: Haha, it can't be iOS because NSTextField & NSTextView :D

Comment: Please set a breakpoint to setDelegate. Let's see if the Textview already exist.

Comment: Yes, awakeFromNib: is called but controlTextDidChange: don't respond.

Comment: Yes but is the textarea nil then?

Comment: Do you implement the protocol like mentioned in another answer?